# What is it dot-separated string resource name for?

Tags: android, string, resources, naming-conventions

I'am using a snake_style for the naming of string resources. In someones code i found another notation, with dots. I couldn't be able to found single word about this topic.

```
<resources>
    <string name="title.activity.first">Activity 1</string>
    <string name="title_activity_second">Activity 2</string>
</resources>
```

Is there any practical advantage/disadvantage of theese styles? Or it is just a cosmetic thing?

Comment: I didn't even realize that `title.activity.first` was possible. It gets converted by the build tools into `R.string.title_activity_first` in `R.java`, so your Java code would be the same for either string declaration format. As a result, I would recommend using underscores, so you have the same syntax in the resource files as in the Java code.

Comment: One advantage could be moving thru text by words with holding ctrl(windows)/alt(mac) + arrows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be just a cosmetic thing, but it has downside of breaking translation check in android studio, so it shows a warning of no translations.
In my case renaming dots to underscores didn't break anything, updated project without any issue.

Comment: That's true. I actually prefer using dots but it breaks into translation check...

Answer (score -2):

In my case, it's braking almost "everything"! It compiles, but I cannot use the autocomplete with any resource (strings, drawables, etc). I'll need to refactor every string resources in that file.