# Error while running project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

I am new to Android Studio and trying to run a sample project related to bluetooth. When I run it I get an Error message which is as follow:

*Error: '.' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore*

I checked with name of the file is **wiced_sense_1_3_update.ota.bin.signed**.This is where I am stuck.

I checked around for some solution and got to know the file name shouldn't contain periods(.). But, when I tried it before in laptop it worked (Had to format the entire thing coz the hard disk crashed).

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and have installed all the necessary SDK through the android SDK manager. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you link from where do you get the sample project from? I'm curious why you have an OTA file inside the resource directory, and whether it's needed to run the project.

Comment: I found it from the [link] (https://github.com/affected/WicedSense)

Comment: I think [CommonsWare's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971563/what-is-it-dot-separated-string-resource-name-for#comment53768106_32971563) is revelant that in some cases, the dot will be replaced into underscore, but not always. Anyway, what if you delete the offending file and try to run it? AFAIK, it shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: now i get the following error:   _Error:(212, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable raw
C:\Users\WicedSense\app\src\main\java\com\broadcom\app\wicedsense\Settings.java_  and  _Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details._ as well.

Comment: the error is originating for the snippet  `sDefaultOtaResource = OtaUiHelper.createRawOtaResource(ctx.getString(R.string.default_ota_fw_version_name), appId, major, minor,ctx.getResources(), R.raw.wiced_sense_1_3_update,mandatory);`

Comment: wherein  **.raw** of `R.raw.wiced_sense_1_3_update,mandatory` cannot be found

Comment: I see, the file is required, but it's complicating the matter with dot in the filename. I don't think I have any solution right now, though it's interesting that it *might* work on somewhere else.